# Makefile linker error about linking .c files when compiling GCC for linux arm64

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-errors, cross-compiling, linker-errors

I am cross-compiling GCC using the Android NDK on linux WSL as I'm targeting ARM64 Android. I need some Android compatible `.so` files such as `libgomp.so` (required by pytorch) that are apparently created when compiling GCC. I will probably also need a GCC executable that works on Android in the future too.

Here is the build script that I wrote to compile GCC:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

export PATH="/home/ben/.local/bin:/opt/gradle/latest/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/"
BUILD_DIR=./build

GCC_DIR=`realpath gcc`

#CONF_FLAGS="--disable-shared"
CONF_FLAGS="--enable-shared --enable-static"

mkdir $BUILD_DIR

PREFIX=`realpath ./install/`
mkdir $PREFIX

echo "install directory: $PREFIX"

pushd $BUILD_DIR

export TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
export TARGET=aarch64-linux-android

export API=23
export AR=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/llvm-ar
export CC=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/$TARGET$API-clang
export AS=$CC
export CXX=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/$TARGET$API-clang++
export LD=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/ld
export RANLIB=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/llvm-ranlib
export STRIP=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/llvm-strip

echo "Cleaning gcc directory via git clean"
pushd $GCC_DIR
git clean -f
popd

$GCC_DIR/configure --host $TARGET --prefix=$PREFIX $CONF_FLAGS
make

popd
```

I need to redefine `PATH` or else I get syntax errors in the makefile, probably because `make` is also defined in Windows' PATH.
The other variables are defined as documented here: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/other_build_systems

`NDK` points to `/home/ben/android-ndk-r23b`

`./configure` seemed to have correctly worked as far as I can tell, but when I run `make`, after a while I get the following errors:

```
ld: error: /home/ben/gcc_build/gcc/gcc/c-family/c-opts.c:1090:(.text+0x1F50): improper alignment for relocation R_AARCH64_LDST64_ABS_LO12_NC: 0x1C842A4 is not aligned to 8 bytes
ld: error: /home/ben/gcc_build/gcc/gcc/c-family/c-opts.c:1271:(.text+0x2830): improper alignment for relocation R_AARCH64_LDST64_ABS_LO12_NC: 0x1C842A4 is not aligned to 8 bytes
ld: error: /home/ben/gcc_build/gcc/gcc/c-family/c-opts.c:0:(.text+0x2854): improper alignment for relocation R_AARCH64_LDST64_ABS_LO12_NC: 0x1C842A4 is not aligned to 8 bytes
ld: error: /home/ben/gcc_build/gcc/gcc/read-md.c:137:(.text+0x254): improper alignment for relocation R_AARCH64_LDST64_ABS_LO12_NC: 0x1C842A4 is not aligned to 8 bytes
ld: error: /home/ben/gcc_build/gcc/gcc/read-md.c:197:(.text+0x500): improper alignment for relocation R_AARCH64_LDST64_ABS_LO12_NC: 0x1C842A4 is not aligned to 8 bytes
ld: error: /home/ben/gcc_build/gcc/gcc/toplev.c:697:(.text+0x25F4): improper alignment for relocation R_AARCH64_LDST64_ABS_LO12_NC: 0x1C842A4 is not aligned to 8 bytes
ld: error: /home/ben/gcc_build/gcc/gcc/toplev.c:711:(.text+0x2770): improper alignment for relocation R_AARCH64_LDST64_ABS_LO12_NC: 0x1C842A4 is not aligned to 8 bytes
ld: error: /home/ben/gcc_build/gcc/gcc/gimple-ssa-warn-restrict.c:2159:(.text+0x3AF4): improper alignment for relocation R_AARCH64_LDST64_ABS_LO12_NC: 0x1C842A4 is not aligned to 8 bytes
ld: error: /home/ben/gcc_build/gcc/gcc/ggc-page.c:694:(.text+0x68): improper alignment for relocation R_AARCH64_LDST64_ABS_LO12_NC: 0x1C842A4 is not aligned to 8 bytes
ld: error: /home/ben/gcc_build/gcc/gcc/ggc-page.c:1744:(.text+0xD3C): improper alignment for relocation R_AARCH64_LDST64_ABS_LO12_NC: 0x1C842A4 is not aligned to 8 bytes
ld: error: /home/ben/gcc_build/gcc/gcc/dumpfile.c:0:(.text+0x2A7C): improper alignment for relocation R_AARCH64_LDST64_ABS_LO12_NC: 0x1C842A4 is not aligned to 8 bytes
ld: error: /home/ben/gcc_build/gcc/gcc/dumpfile.c:0:(.text+0x2A9C): improper alignment for relocation R_AARCH64_LDST64_ABS_LO12_NC: 0x1C842A4 is not aligned to 8 bytes
ld: error: /home/ben/gcc_build/gcc/gcc/dumpfile.c:0:(.text+0x30D0): improper alignment for relocation R_AARCH64_LDST64_ABS_LO12_NC: 0x1C842A4 is not aligned to 8 bytes
ld: error: /home/ben/gcc_build/gcc/gcc/dumpfile.c:0:(.text+0x420C): improper alignment for relocation R_AARCH64_LDST64_ABS_LO12_NC: 0x1C842A4 is not aligned to 8 bytes
clang-12: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The failing command is this one:

```
/home/ben/android-ndk-r23b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android23-clang++ -no-pie   -g -O2 -DIN_GCC    -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-error=format-diag -Wmissing-format-attribute -Woverloaded-virtual -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -o cc1 c/c-lang.o c-family/stub-objc.o attribs.o c/c-errors.o c/c-decl.o c/c-typeck.o c/c-convert.o c/c-aux-info.o c/c-objc-common.o c/c-parser.o c/c-fold.o c/gimple-parser.o c-family/c-common.o c-family/c-cppbuiltin.o c-family/c-dump.o c-family/c-format.o c-family/c-gimplify.o c-family/c-indentation.o c-family/c-lex.o c-family/c-omp.o c-family/c-opts.o c-family/c-pch.o c-family/c-ppoutput.o c-family/c-pragma.o c-family/c-pretty-print.o c-family/c-semantics.o c-family/c-ada-spec.o c-family/c-ubsan.o c-family/known-headers.o c-family/c-attribs.o c-family/c-warn.o c-family/c-spellcheck.o aarch64-c.o glibc-c.o \
  cc1-checksum.o libbackend.a main.o libcommon-target.a libcommon.a ../libcpp/libcpp.a ../libdecnumber/libdecnumber.a libcommon.a ../libcpp/libcpp.a ./../intl/libintl.a  ../libbacktrace/.libs/libbacktrace.a ../libiberty/libiberty.a ../libdecnumber/libdecnumber.a   -L/home/ben/gcc_build/build/./gmp/.libs -L/home/ben/gcc_build/build/./mpfr/src/.libs -L/home/ben/gcc_build/build/./mpc/src/.libs -lmpc -lmpfr -lgmp -rdynamic  -L./../zlib -lz
```

I'm not sure what's happening since it seems `ld` is trying to link `.c` files, which I don't think is normal. I also don't understand how can these files be involved since they appear nowhere in the command, neither does the `gcc/gcc/` directory.
I don't think compiling in WSL is the issue, though it previously caused some issues but I think I solved them.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: I don't see where the command would link .c files. I think the error message only references the .c files corresponding to the .o files where the errors were found. Maybe the .c files were compiled with wrong settings leading to a wrong alignment. Do I understand right that you want to build a GCC executable that can *run* on ARM64 Android?

Comment: @Bodo I don't really need the GCC executable yet, but I will need some .so files created in the process, most notably libgomp.so .

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add this information. What exactly do you want to achieve? How exactly did you configure and run the build process? I did not find enough documentation. Is `libgomp.so` part of the GCC build?

Comment: @Bodo I edited the question. `libgomp` is a folder in the GCC source tree, since pytorch and other libraries that I need to use on Android will probably require other "core" libraries, I thought it would be easier to compile the entire GCC ecosystem.